# How can I obtain and analyze data from a file without the code being messy?

Tags: c, file

I made a program that reads a list of grades from a file and calculates the GPA. I have no idea how to properly modularize a program like this, because both the the calculating and the file reading happen simultaneously.

Here is text file contents:

```
Ariel Lewis
Biology    A 4.0
Statistics C 4.0
History    A 3.0
Tennis     A 1.0
English    B 3.0
```

Here is my code:

```
#pragma warning (disable:4996)


#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE 20

#define ERROR -1

float GPA(int, int);
int CoursePoints(int, int);
int GradeToPoints(char);


int main() 
{
FILE * fpCredits;

char singleLine[MAX_LINE];
char gradeLetter = '_';
int totalPoints = 0;
int totalCredits = 0;
int credits = 0;
int gradePoint = 0;
int i = 0;

/*
fpCredits = fopen("grades.txt", "w");
fprintf(fpCredits, "Ariel Lewis\n");
fprintf(fpCredits, "Biology    A 4.0\n");
fprintf(fpCredits, "Statistics C 4.0\n");
fprintf(fpCredits, "History    A 3.0\n");
fprintf(fpCredits, "Tennis     A 1.0\n");
fprintf(fpCredits, "English    B 3.0\n");
rewind(fpCredits);
*/

fpCredits = fopen("grades.txt", "r");

// DISPLAY INFORMATION
fgets(singleLine, MAX_LINE, fpCredits);
for (i = 0; singleLine[i] != '\n'; i++) {
    printf("%c", singleLine[i]);
}
printf("'s Grade Point Average Calculator\n\n");
printf("Course Name     Grade Earned     Number of Credits Earned\n");
while (!feof(fpCredits)) {
    fgets(singleLine, MAX_LINE, fpCredits);
    for (i = 0; singleLine[i] != ' '; i++) {
        printf("%c", singleLine[i]);
    }
    printf("    ");
    printf("\t");
    for (i = 0; singleLine[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (singleLine[i] == 'A' || singleLine[i] == 'B' || singleLine[i] == 'C' || singleLine[i] == 'D' || singleLine[i] == 'F') {
            if (singleLine[i - 1] == ' ' && singleLine[i + 1] == ' ') {
                if (singleLine[i + 2] >= '0' && singleLine[i + 2] <= '4') {
                    credits = singleLine[i + 2] - '0';
                }
                else {
                    printf("\n ERROR:FILE_SPACING \n");
                    break;
                }
                gradeLetter = singleLine[i];
                printf("%c                %.1f", gradeLetter, (float)credits);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
rewind(fpCredits);

// CALCULATE INFORMATION
while (!feof(fpCredits)) {
    fgets(singleLine, MAX_LINE, fpCredits);
    for (i = 0; singleLine[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (singleLine[i] == 'A' || singleLine[i] == 'B' || singleLine[i] == 'C' || singleLine[i] == 'D' || singleLine[i] == 'F') {
            if (singleLine[i - 1] == ' ' && singleLine[i + 1] == ' ') {
                if (singleLine[i + 2] >= '0' && singleLine[i + 2] <= '4') {
                    credits = singleLine[i + 2] - '0';
                }
                else {
                    printf("\n ERROR:FILE_SPACING \n");
                    break;
                }
                if (singleLine[i] == 'F') {
                    credits = 0;
                }
                totalCredits = totalCredits + credits;
                gradePoint = GradeToPoints(singleLine[i]);
                totalPoints = totalPoints + CoursePoints(gradePoint, credits);
            }
        }
    }
}
rewind(fpCredits);

printf("The GPA for this student is:   %.2f and credits earned are: %d.\n\n", GPA(totalPoints, totalCredits), totalCredits);

fclose(fpCredits);

return 0;
}


float GPA(int points, int credits) 
{
    return (float)points / (float)credits;
}


int CoursePoints(int gradePoints, int credits) 
{
    return gradePoints * credits;
}


int GradeToPoints(char grade) 
{
switch (grade) {
case 'A':
    return 4;
case 'B':
    return 3;
case 'C':
    return 2;
case 'D':
    return 1;
case 'F':
    return 0;
default:
    printf("\n ERROR:DEFAULT \n");
    return ERROR;
}
printf("\n ERROR:SKIPPED \n");
return ERROR;
}
```

Comment: Post grades.txt or post part of it.  Need to understand how your input file looks like.

Comment: Okay, I added file contents.

Comment: The usage of sscanf() can simplify your code.  sscanf( singleLine, "%s%c%f", courseName, grade, credit );  where courseName can be char[20], grade is char and grade is a float variable.

Comment: There is no need to rewind().  This can be done with one read.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note: modularization is not about simultaneous execution, its ok to read and calculate at the same time, but different modules should perform actual job.

One suggestion how you can make it work is to start with pseudo-code for your algorithm:

```
total grade = 0;
total grade count = 0;
for every grade in dataset:
    print this grade

    total grade += this grade;
    total grade count++;

print average grade
```

now, this algorithm does not know anything about files, it works with "dataset", how this can be translated into code, one variant (pseudo c style):

**Grade module**

Implementation is to put this into grade.h file

```
struct Grade {
 char gradeLetter;
 int gradeValue;
 int gradeCredits;
}
```

**File based dataset module**

Implementation is to put this into FileBaseGradeDataSource.h/c file

```
FILE* getDataSource() {
    ///fopen....
}

void closeDataSource(FILE*f) {
    ///fclose
}

boolean hasMore(FILE*f) {
    return !eof(f);
}

Grade getNextGrade(FILE*f) {
    // your logic to read and parse string from file
}
```

**Main module**

Implementation is to put this into main.c

```
FILE* datasource = getDataSource(); 

int totalPoints = 0;
int totalCredits = 0;
while (hasMore(datasource)) {
    Grade grade = getNextGrade(datasource);
    // printf, save
}
// print average

closeDataSource(datasource);
```